# Please help me restore windows and windows data after intervention of "Windows 7 Boot Updater" program (preferred without load drive)

Tags: windows-7, bootloader, windows-7-restore

Today I wanted to decorate the system(Windows 7 x64) a little.

I found in the Internet that can change the animation of loading Windows by **Windows 7 Boot Updater** program(I downloaded it [here](http://www.coderforlife.com/projects/win7boot/); **FOR YOUR SAFETY, DON'T DOWNLOAD THIS**). 
By that program I installed loader animation....
   I restart windows.
Now when I start the computer this appears(Sample translation):

```
Dispatcher Windows load

Windows failed to start. This may have been due to a recent hardware or software configuration change. To fix the error:
1. Insert the Windows installation disk and restart your computer.
2. Select the language settings, and then click next.
3. Select "repair your computer".
If this disk is missing, contact your system administrator or computer manufacturer for help.

Status: 0xc0000098
Information: an unexpected error occurred.
```

I haven't a windows load disk. 
On computer are installed pirate windows. 
I think someone on this forum faced a similar problem. 
Please help (preferably without reinstall Windows), because on the computer a lot of important information.

Comment: This cannot be solved without a Windows 7 installation media.  Your installation is currently corrupt, the only way to even have a chance of fixing your problem, is by booting to an installation media and repairing your installation.  Even if you do that, it's not guaranteed to solve the problem, which is the reason programs like you used are unsupported and unwise to even use.

Comment: @Ramhound, but if I'll reinstall windows then I may restore data on hard disk?

Comment: If you reinstall Windows on your current disk you would overwrite your data.  Unless you want to decrease your chances of recovering your data you shouldn't do that.  **I never suggested you reinstall Windows.**

Comment: @Ramhound, OK, I will not reinstall system now. Can you explain exactly how data recovery will take place at the expense of disk and which disks can be used to restore Windows 7 (x64 Maximal pirate)? In other words, what kind of disk will work for me if I don't have the disk with the system?(The computer was shipped with a pirate system already installed)

Comment: Just before I never tried to recovery/install windows